# Cache Object Evicting by JMS Message Listener Notifier

Tags: caching, jakarta-ee, jms, listener, eclipselink

Suppose there are 2 Java EE applications. The second application depends on the first application as jar and war. I am using a Class extending JMS `MessageListener` and `onMessage()`. I send the Object that is modified in the first application. When receiving the JMS message from the second application I evict the object and refresh the cache. But the child `@OneToMany` is not being evicted. What would be the problem?

I read that if the `Cascade.ALL` is put as annotation on the child so when parent is evicted, child is also. What would be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a problem and you may have mis-read Cascade.ALL as it does not apply for eviction. There is no cascade type that covers eviction at all in JPA. When you evict an object from a remote cache, there is nothing to say that the OneToMany relationship within the cached object was even loaded. It cannot know which referenced entities to invalidate without loading that relationship, and if it does have state, it might miss the newly added entities if that OneToMany was modified in the remote cache.

If you want to cascade eviction, you'll have to send an eviction message that includes the graph on your own. Your application should know and have loaded the graph and can send out the classes and IDs associated to the remote servers, avoiding them from any need to hit the database to load things just to ensure they are evicted. Doing so would entirely depend on your reasoning for evicting the graph though, as it seems like it would be an unnecessary burden: many leaf nodes in graphs generally remain unchanged, and if they are, have their own cache eviction policies that would evict them from remote caches.